# Limit user access in Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

This is mostly playing around at the moment but I'm attempting to use Azure AD B2C as the login provider / user store for a website I'm working on.

I want to limit what users can access based on a user level.

At the moment, in order to handle this I have a database entry for UserLevel that stores the users OID, and an enum for the user level (admin, moderator, user etc) and then for page / api access I've set up a requirement that checks the authenticated user is in the UserLevel repository, and that their level matches, or exceeds the required level.

What I'm wondering is if there are any major problems with doing things this way / is there a better way to handle this.

Comment: You can store the usrelevel as custom attribute in azure ad b2c as application_claim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **Custom Attributes** to save all your User properties - it will act like DB columns in B2C.

***How to create?***

1. Navigate to the directory that contains your B2C tenant.
2. Choose **All services** in the top-left corner of the Azure portal, search for and select **Azure AD B2C**.
3. Select **User attributes**, and then select **Add**.
4. Provide a **Name** for the custom attribute (for example, `UserLevel`)
5. Choose a **Data Type** as `String` (Note that only String, Boolean, and Int are available).
6. Optionally, enter a **Description** for informational purposes.
7. Click **Create**.

The custom attribute is now available in the list of User attributes and for use in your user flows.

***How to use in your User Flows?***

1. In your Azure AD B2C tenant, select **User flows**.
2. Select your policy (for example, "B2C_1_SignupSignin") to open it.
3. Select **User attributes** and then select the custom attribute (for example, `UserLevel`). Click **Save**.
4. Select **Application claims** and then select the custom attribute.
5. Click **Save**.

You should now see `UserLevel` in the list of attributes collected during the sign-up journey, and **see it in the token sent back to your application** - based on which you will be able to identify the access you want to give to that user (instead of making another DB call which will increase latency).

Comment: Thanks for that, but this approach requires the users setting their own user level and I don't trust users not to just say "Yeah I'm an admin".

Comment: For that case, you can have a User Management portal for Admin and set this custom attirbute value using Microsoft Graph SDK - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http     Or you can also do this manually if you want by going to the Azure portal and setting it's vaue.